# Как сделать так чтобы текст то появлялся, то исчезал в Unity3d?

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет, хотелось бы узнать, как сделать так, чтобы текст (Text MeshPro) в Unity3D, то появлялся, то исчезал и тоже самое с кнопкой...

Comment: Можно менять прозрачность (добавив компонент `CanvasGroup`), можно просто активировать/отключать объект. Сделать это можно в коде, а можно аниматором. Вы что-нибудь из этого пробовали? Где столкнулись с трудностями/ошибками?

Comment: Создавайте простую анимацию с помощью компонента Animation. В этом вам поможет это (https://youtu.be/jh4kjEoxc9Y) видео. Я бы хотел помочь но как вам передать анимацию?

Comment: нет, я ничего из этого пока не пробовал ( попробовал написать код, добавил скрипт к тексту, но ничего не произошло).

Answer (score 1):

Скрипт делает то же, что и таковой у товарища Alt_F4, но короче и работает не только с текстом, а с любым графическим элементом.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;


public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private Graphic g;
    [SerializeField] private Color   color;
    [SerializeField] private float   period = 1;


    void Update () {
        float a = Mathf.PingPong (Time.time, period) / period;
        g.color = new Color (color.r, color.g, color.b, a);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам либо надо сделать анимацию, либо писать такой скрипт. Я бы предпочёл анимацию.
А скрипт будет такой:

```cs
public Text text;
float transition, textTransparence;
bool invisibility = true;

void Start()
{
    textTransparence = text.color.a * 255;
    //transition показывает за сколько времени текст будет исчезнуть а потом появляться.
    transition = 3.0f;
}

private void Update()
{
    if (invisibility)
    {
        textTransparence -= Time.deltaTime * (255.0f / transition * 2);
        if (textTransparence <= 0.0f)
        {
            invisibility = false;
        }
    }
    else if (!invisibility)
    {
        textTransparence += Time.deltaTime * (255.0f / transition * 2);
        if (textTransparence >= 255.0f)
        {
            invisibility = true;
        }
    }
    text.color = new Color32((byte)text.color.r, (byte)text.color.g, (byte)text.color.b, (byte)textTransparence);
}
```

---

А это результат

[image]